# Django caching techniques

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to minimize db hit rate with my queries. So I need to clarify in my case if I hit the db with the following code.

```
contract = Contract.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk']) # get queryset
context['contract'] = contract.filter(version=self.kwargs['version'])[0] # hit db or cache?
context['latest_version'] = contract.latest('creation_date').version # hit db or cache?
```

Comment: Hit and hit. Details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Comment: @arocks so if use use `contract = Contract.objects.all()` and the work with `contract` object i wont hit db again?

Comment: The way Django works, that line doesn't hit the database immediately. When it gets evaluated (say in a template), it hits the database. So the best way to count the hits is to use a tool like the Django Debug Toolbar.